What is the name of this LCD connector?
I currently bought a 1.69 inch display, which has this connector:
 
Screenshots taken from the vendor's site: https://www.waveshare.com/1.69inch-lcd-module.htm
I was trying to figure out what the name of the connector is. On the website it is written that this is a "GH1.25 connector." As I searched the web for this connector, they all look a bit different (thicker).
Can anyone please confirm that this is the right connector or tell me the real name of this connector?

My Identiconn utility identifed that as a Molex Panelmate.

Male PCB header: Molex 0532610871
Female plug housing: Molex 0510210800


{Source: DigiKey}

GH1.25 connector

That's a generic part number that vendors use for one of the many Chinese companies that make knock-offs of the original Molex Panelmate. The real GH connector is made by JST and looks nothing like your connector.

Thank you, these parts seem to match the real connectors used.

useful site! bookmarked
